# how to limit BroadcastReceiver onReceive to be called for only incoming calls

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an app that listens for incoming calls and depending upon the number sends an SMS to that number. Everything is working on incoming the `onReceive` is called and SMS is sent but as soon as the call is rejected either by called or caller party `onReceive` is called again and SMS is sent again. How can I limit this, so when a call is received only then the `onReceive` is called?

Following is the simple version of my code:

My BroadcastReceiver

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

```
public class Telephone extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d("onReceive", "Got Call Signal");

    }

}
```

in Manifest:

```
         <receiver android:name="com.example.testbroadcastreceiver.Telephone" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Permission used:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990590/how-to-detect-phone-call-broadcast-receiver-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to register an [PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#LISTEN_CALL_STATE) for receiving only incoming call inside BroadcastReceiver as:

```
public class Telephone extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context mContext;
    private Intent mIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mContext = context;
        mIntent = intent;
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)              
                 context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int events = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE;
        tm.listen(phoneStateListener, events);
    }

    private final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = 
                                                new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            String callState = "UNKNOWN";
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:

                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                                // DO YOUR WORK HERE
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                          if(incomingNumber.length() >0){

                                  // incoming call
                                 // DO YOUR WORK HERE when call is received
                                 // SEND SMS HERE
                            }
                           else{
                                      // outgoing call
                              }
                break;
            }

            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it logically like this:

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override    
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener=new MyPhoneStateListener();
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
  }
}

public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
  public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String incomingNumber){
  switch(state){
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
      Log.d("DEBUG", "IDLE");
    break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
      Log.d("DEBUG", "OFFHOOK");
    break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
      Log.d("DEBUG", "RINGING");
//place your sms code here
    break;
    }
  } 
}
```